# Entity Framework Code First contraint when one column value depends on another

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, constraints

I have the following model:

```
class RentOrder
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add constraint in Entity Framework Code First that `StartDate` must be always less than `EndDate`? The only way I know is to add it by executing SQL-command in overridden `Seed` method. Is there more simple way, without SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem now, as I mentioned in question, is to write SQL-commands in `Seed` method:

```
public class MyDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDatabaseContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE Orders
            ADD CONSTRAINT C_Dates CHECK(EndDate > StartDate)");
    }
}
```

And call somewhere on the application start:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDatabaseInitializer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the set method and throw a custom exception if the enddate is less then the start date.

Comment: Where can I implement it? Do you mean setter of `EndDate` property?

Comment: I did mean setter, like shuniar's example. If RentOrder is the EF autogenerated class, you can inherit from it and create a new class to be used, with the updated setters. You can then set the original RentOrder to not be accessible outside your EF layer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement it in both because you would still be able to set the opposite. Here is a quick example (assuming the start and end date cannot be the same day):

```
class RentOrder
{
    public DateTime StartDate 
    { 
      get { return _startDate }; 
      set 
      {
          if (value >= _endDate)
              throw new Exception("Start Date cannot be greater than End Date");

          _startDate = value; 
      };
    }
    private DateTime _startDate;

    public DateTime EndDate
    { 
      get { return _endDate}; 
      set 
      {
          if (value <= _startDate)
              throw new Exception("End Date cannot be less than Start Date");

          _endDate = value; 
      };
    }
    private DateTime _endDate;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that its not just a class. He is mapped to database using EF and I need to set that constraints on database side, so any code that will connect to DB (possibly, not only from my application) will save always correct dates.

Comment: Another problem with your check (even if I will use it on client side) is that I can't set for example incorrect `EndDate` first and then fix `StartDate`.

Comment: Another option is to just add a ValidateDates() method that returns whether the dates are set correctly.